# Windows seven can't detect mouse and keyboard on boot

Tags: windows-7

I am using a hp pavilion dm4 dual booted with Ubuntu and windows seven.However recently windows seven reported an error on boot about a file.I replaced the file through Ubuntu and now windows seven can boot up to the log in screen.But the keyboard and mouse are not detected.I have tried booting into safe mode but the problem is the same.Any advice?

Comment: What type of devices - USB? What was the exact error? You "replaced the file through Ubuntu"? Which one? Where did you get the replacement from? Do we start guessing? :)

Comment: Its a laptop so of course am talking about the built in keyboard and touch pad.As for the file,initially windows had an error on boot saying srvcli.dll in C:\Windows\System32 was corrupted and should be re-installed.I downloaded the file from http://answers.microsoft.com ,i replaced the corrupted file.

Comment: "Its a laptop so of course am talking about the built in keyboard and touch pad" - Not to quibble, but you said "mouse" and just because it's a laptop doesn't mean one can take these things for granted. It's always better to be clear when you're asking for help. Have you tried running `sfc /scannow` from an elevated command prompt?

Comment: ok i appreciate the correction

Comment: how do i do that?

Comment: Type `cmd` at the Start Menu, right-click cmd.exe, Run as Admin, type `sfc /scannow` and press Enter.

Comment: @Karan How could the OP do that? The OP says the mouse and keyboard do not work.

Comment: @BenjiWiebe: Doh! Was gonna add somewhere that he'll need to try with a USB keyboard/mouse, but completely forgot as I switched to another tab. Thanks for catching that!